# Javascript : Enter Key Press

Tags: asp.net, javascript, keypress, enter

Good Morning...

I am using java script in each page to trigger the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press Event inside the textbox.
It is working fine. Now i want to place the code in the `.js` file for global access.

```
 function EnterKeyPress(id,e) {
       // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
       if (window.event) { e = window.event; }
       if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 121) {

           window.document.getElementById('<%= ibtnSubmit.ClientID %>').click();
       } 
   }
```

I dont want to hard code the control id. Can anybody help me please..

Answer (score 9):

You can use your *id* parameter instead of the ControlID, and when you use this function in your pages, you can pass the ControlID as a parameter:

```
function EnterKeyPress(id,e) {
  if (window.event) { e = window.event; }
   if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 121) {
     document.getElementById(id).click();
   }
}
```

You are using ASP .NET, so in your code-behind you can assign the keypress event:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress",
                      string.Format("EnterPressKey('{0}', event);", ibtnSubmit.ClientID));
```

But wait, that functionality is already done on ASP .NET, you can use [ASP:Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) controls to wrap your common controls, and you can assign a [DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) for the panel to indicate which button gets clicked when the  Panel control has focus and the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can do it like this:

```
$("input[id*=ibtnSubmit]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to submit when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, then you don't need javascript. It will do so automatically. Just put the textbox inside a form element with an action:

```
<form action="process.php">
  <input type="text">when the enter key is pressed, the form is submitted and sent to process.php</input>
</form>
```